# PostgreSQL: How to select set of text fields to variable?

Tags: postgresql, function

How to do in PGSQL something like this:
I have a SQL Server function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[gettags] 
(   
    @id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(1024) 
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(1024);
DECLARE @m NVARCHAR(2);
SELECT  @s = N'', @m=N'';
SELECT @s=@s+@m+word, @m=N',' from dbo.tags where id=@id AND LEN(ISNULL(word,N''))>0;
IF LEN(@s)>0
    RETURN @s;
RETURN NULL;
END
```

I am trying to create a corresponding function in PGSQL.
How I can select set of resulting fields into variable like it is done in the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With my - rather rudimentary - knowledge of SQL Server programming, you seem to want to aggregate the values in the `word` column of table `dbo.tags`, using a comma `,` as separator and excluding `NULL` and empty string values. In PostgreSQL this is far easier than in SQL Server:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.gettags (_id integer) RETURNS text AS $$
    SELECT string_agg(word, ',')
    FROM dbo.tags
    WHERE id = _id
      AND word IS NOT NULL AND length(word) > 0;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Since this is a single SQL statement, it is a `sql` function, not `plpgsql`, which is more efficient. You could even forget about the function entirely and use the SQL statement directly.